# TextBlock not rendering entire text on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

So I'm creating an app that requires for a TextBlock to have a marquee effect if its width is longer than the bounds of the page in Landscape mode. I managed to get it to marquee just fine using TranslateTransform animations, but it seems that my TextBlock's text is being cut out.

Is there a way to make it so that this behavior doesn't happen or is there a workaround?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `TextBlock` in a `Canvas` and then apply the animation. Also make sure that you set the `TextWrapping` property to `NoWrap` and set the width to `Auto` so that it spans only one line.

Comment: Thank you my good man, it works perfectly fine now! I would have never thought of that solution on my own.

Comment: Just curious how you did your marquee, can you share you sample XAML/C#? Or a link to your blog or something?

Comment: @UzairSajid your answer is OK. It seems that only Canvas can work in this case, also the TextWrapping and Width Auto are like charm